# Creating a class that executes python in c#

Tags: c#, python

I have a python code. I need to execute the python script from my c# program. After searching a bit about this, I came to know that there is mainly two ways of executing a python script from c#.

One by using 'Process' command and

the other by using Iron Python.

My question might seem dumb, is there any other way through which I can execute a python script? To be more specific, can I create a class , lets say 'Python' in c#  and a member function 'execute_script' which doesn't use any api like iron python or doesn't create a process for executing the script, so that if call 'execute_scipt(mypythonprogram.py)' , my script gets executed. Sorry if this seems dumb. If this is possible, please do help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not a C# developer, but aren't your idea to call `execute_scipt("mypythonprogram.py")` and the option to use [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process(v=vs.110).aspx) basically the same thing? Wouldn't your `Python` class just be a thin wrapper around `System`?

Comment: Do you just need to execute the script? Do you need to get any results back into C#? Can you guarantee that the target system will always have Python installed, and on the PATH? If you don't have special requirements, Process is likely to be the easiest way by far.

Comment: No I don't require any result from the script. Just execution is required. I'm currently trying to develop a framework. My mentor asked me not to go with Process as it might slower the process and some security issues also.  Thats the reason why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed python into your application. View the python documentation section *Extending and Embedding* > [*Embedding Python in Another Application*](https://docs.python.org/2.7/extending/embedding.html).

edit: this requires C++, but it should not be too difficult to build a C++ wrapper that you can use from C# (see [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235281.aspx)).

Comment: The MSDN article involves creating a C++/CLI bridge between the native C++ code and the managed C# code, and this also requires having references to at least the Python headers, which will require a little extra legwork on a Windows development environment. All this sounds possible, but it's a lot of work just to run a script which (depending on his needs) might be doable with a one-liner shell command.

Comment: That's true, but I believe this is the only way to do it without a 3rd party API, or creating a new process, as the asker wanted. This also has the advantage of not requiring users to have Python installed.

Answer (score 0):

Can you create a C# class that calls a Python script without using Iron Python and without using any external API? No. That is not possible. You have a few other choices:

1. Integrate the Python runtime into your program.

Smead already described one way to do this. It will work, and it does avoid creating another process, but it will be a lot of work to get it running, and it is still technically using an API. I do not recommend this for a single Python script where you don't need to pass data back and forth, but it's good to know that option exists if your other options don't pan out.

2. Use the Process module.

This is probably what I would do. Process has security concerns when a malicious user can cause you to execute bogus shell commands, or if the malicious user can replace the contents of the Python script. It is quite safe when you can lock down those two things.

The speed is unlikely to be a concern. It will literally only take a few minutes to set up a C# program with a process call, so if your mentor is concerned about speed, just write it and measure the speed to see if it's actually a problem.

3. Consider rewriting the script in C#

C# is a very expressive language with a very strong standard library, so assuming your script is not thousands of lines long, and does not use any obscure Python libraries, this might actually not be much work. If you really must not use Process, this would be the next solution I would consider.